# How to nested sort with limit and top results elasticsearch?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I want to sort 7 most expansive products with validate time ascending. I did:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 7,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "price": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }, {
        "validate_time": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }]
}
```

But I want this top 7 expansive products ordered by validate_time

Comment: I tried nested_filter and doesn't work... I use first sort to find TOP 7 and then sort by validate_date.. I searched many sites before ask...

Answer (score 0):

Who wants to see the proper answer: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-search-with-limit-and-top-results/33556